# Строки отображаются без отступа

Tags: html, css

Есть код:

```css
body {
  font: 10pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; /* Шрифт на веб-странице */
  background: #e1dfb9; /* Цвет фона */
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.1em; /* Размер шрифта */
  color: #800040; /* Цвет текста */
  margin-top: 0; /* Отступ сверху */
}
#container {
  width: 500px; /* Ширина слоя */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Выравнивание по центру */
  background: #f0f0f0; /* Цвет фона левой колонки */
}
#header {
  font-size: 2.2em; /* Размер текста */
  text-align: center; /* Выравнивание по центру */
  padding: 5px; /* Отступы вокруг текста */
  background: #8fa09b  /* Цвет фона шапки */
  color: #ffe; /* Цвет текста */
}
#content {
  margin-left: 130px; /* Отступ слева */
  padding: 10px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
  background: #fff; /* Цвет фона правой колонки */
}
#footer {
  background: #8fa09b; /* Цвет фона подвала */
  color: #fff; /* Цвет текста */
  padding: 5px; /* Отступы вокруг текста */
  clear: left; /* Отменяем действие float */
}
#leftcol { /* Левая колонка */
  float: left; /* Обтекание справа */
  width: 200px; /* Ширина колонки */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h2>HomeПейж</h2>
    <p align="right">Добро пожаловать.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="leftcol">
    <p>Главная</p>
    <p>Обо мне</p>
    <p>Полезные ссылки</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Как со мной связаться?
      <br>
      <a href="https://vk.com/aftonweb">VKontakte</a>
    </p>
    <hr>
    <p>Как заказать сайт?
      <br>Сайты делаю бесплатно. Достаточно лишь написать мне на почту -
      <mark>aftonweb@gmail.com</mark>
    </p>
    <hr>
    <p>Дабы преобразить сайт,
      <br>Достаточно лишь нажать на кнопку.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

В чем проблема:[image: Вот такой вот сайт]

Почему последние строки отображаются без отступа? (Не так, как все)

```
<p>Дабы преобразить сайт,<br>
                Достаточно лишь нажать на кнопку.</p>
```

Comment: все там нормально с отступами. Это у вас верхние параграфы вправо смещены из за #leftcol

Comment: Очень рекомендую в любом браузере тыкаете мышкой (правой кнопкой) - выбираете инспектировать элемент. Там такие вещи наглядно видно

Comment: а можно мне сайт заказать?

Answer (score 1):

```
#content {
    margin-left: 200px;
    ...
```